# How does $e^{-A(D)}$ and $D^{\alpha}$ commute?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $u$ be a Schwartz function as defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space.
Let $D = (D_1, ..., D_n)$ where $D_j u = - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}$.
Let $A$ be a real quadratic form  s.t. $A(x_1, .., x_n) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to prove that
$$
\| e^{-A(D)} (D^{\alpha} u)  \|_2 = \|  D^{\alpha} (e^{-A(D)} u)  \|_2.
$$
Here $\alpha = (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$. This is stated without any explanation in the book I am reading. Any hint on how I can get this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the spectral theorem that $D$ commutes with $f(D)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try giving a proof that does not use the spectral theorem:

Let start by noticing that the operator $A(D): \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ is bounded by the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis)#Between_F-spaces). Indeed the Schwarz space is a Frechet space (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375020/schwartz-space-is-a-fr%C3%A9chet-space))

In particular, given a set of functions $f_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}$ we have
$$
A(D)f_n \to 0
$$
in $\mathcal{S}$. So the graph of $A(D)$ is closed. As $A(D)$ is bounded we can define (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204592/operator-exponential))
$$
e^{-A(D)}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-A(D))^n}{n!}
$$
as a bounded operator without the need of the spectral theorem

By Parseval theorem
$$
\| e^{-A(D)} (D^{\alpha} u)  \|_2 =\|\widehat{e^{-A(D)} (D^{\alpha} u)}\|_2=\|e^{-A(\|x\|)}x^\alpha \hat{u}\|_2=\|x^\alpha e^{-A(\|x\|)} \hat{u}\|_2= \|  D^{\alpha} (e^{-A(D)} u)  \|_2
$$
(probably you don't even need Parseval, you can simply use the fact that
$[D^\alpha, D^\beta]=0$)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this. I am trying to understand which closed graph theorem is used to show $e^{-A(D)}$ is a well defined bounded operator? (I have looked around online and there seems to be few variants) Could you possibly clarify this please? Thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyT. I have added some references

Comment: @JohnnyT. if your doubt was on the fact that $e^{-A(D)}$ is well defined. 

If $L$ is a bounded, linear operator you have the bound
$$\left\|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{L^n}{n!} \right\|\le e^{\|L\|}$$ so $e^L$ is bounded

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications!!